# find the values that ONLY take one value in another column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a panel dataset that contains many days' info on each ID number. There is one variable that takes the number of months in which the clients did *something*.
I want to find the clients that only reached 1 month, so the clients that never reached months 2, 3, etc.

Here is a sample of my data. The date column is in str format.

```
Client| Date        | Months
1     | 04/01/2019  | 1
1     | 05/01/2019  | 1
1     | 06/01/2019  | 2
2     | 11/01/2019  | 1
2     | 12/01/2019  | 1
2     | 13/01/2019  | 1
2     | 14/01/2019  | 1
3     | 20/01/2019  | 1
3     | 21/01/2019  | 2
3     | 22/01/2019  | 2
3     | 23/01/2019  | 2
3     | 24/01/2019  | 3 
3     | 25/01/2019  | 3 
3     | 26/01/2019  | 3
```

In this example only client 2 would be selected. I would make a list or something like that to store the client numbers that follow the rule.

The code I tried was

```
df.loc[df["MONTHS"]==1, "CLIENT"].unique()
```

which didn't give me what I wanted (this includes all client id's that ever had 1 month, but not the ones that *only* had 1 month)

Any ideas are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
s = df.set_index('Client')['Months'].eq(1).groupby(level=0).all()
s[s].index
```

Result:

```
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64', name='Client')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows where there is only one unique month and filter :

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["Client"]).Months.transform("nunique").eq(1)]

Client  Date    Months
3   2   11/01/2019  1
4   2   12/01/2019  1
5   2   13/01/2019  1
6   2   14/01/2019  1
```

If you just want the Client number :

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["Client"]).Months.transform("nunique").eq(1), "Client"].unique()[0]
```

OR

```
df.groupby("Client").Months.nunique().loc[lambda x: x == 1].index[0]
```